# How to detect that the entire period of C++ random engine has been consumed

Tags: c++, c++11, random, stdarray

I want to write a small (fast) C++ program which essentially "detects" that the entire period of a `std::minstd_rand0`  engine has been consumed. In other words I want to detect when the sequence is repeating (and also measure the time required for the sequence to repeat). I don't care about the target distribution (it can be uniform).

Any ideas on how I should proceed? One option I was considering is to create two `std::array` variables. In the first `std::array` I would store say the 10000 first pseudo-random variates returned by `std:minstd_rand0`. I would then proceed by filling the other `std::array` with successive blocks of 10000 variates and compare the contents of the 2 arrays after each pass of 10000 variates. I would consider that the entire period has been consummed once the 2 arrays are equals.

Would this approach be sensible?

Comment: Many times, the exact period of the generator will be known and stated in the docs, so you could look it up there.

Comment: Also, if the period is not a multiple of 10000, your algorithm will return a multiple of the period that is.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What's your goal?

Comment: Let's say I don't know anything about a random generator (I am an external observator). And I want to "guess" when the sequence has been consumed.

Comment: @Mooing Duck. I don't care about the real period which is much bigger than 10000. What I am considering is that the sequence is repeating when I get the same 10000 values as my initial array.

Comment: @BigLudinski: My point is, if the period is 70,000, and you check blocks of 10,000, you will fill the arrays 70 times before they match, and incorrectly conclude the period is 700,000.  Instead, you'll want something like the [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

Comment: @James McLeod just playing around with random generators :)

Comment: @JamesMcLeod The idea is to show that if the period of a random generator, in this case the std::minstd_rand0 is too short, then you can not only "detect" when the sequence is repeating, but you can also "guess" the sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard random number engines can be compared to each other--they compare equal if and only if they have the same state.

Therefore, you can pretty easily measure the period with code that:

1. Creates two default constructed generators
2. Executes a loop generating a number from one of the generators, and incrementing a count.
3. Until the two generators compare equal again.

At least in my quick test of `std::minstd_rand0`, I get a result of

```
 2147483646
```

Needless to say, this is a lot more practical with `std::minstd_rand0` than with `std::mt19937` (for one obvious example).

Comment: that's the modulus

Comment: @BigLudinski: Close, but no. The modulus is `2147483647` (2^31-1). Part of the design of the minimal standard generator is that it's a full-period generator, though, so that's pretty much what we expect.

Comment: This solution only works when the initial state is part of the cycle. Can this be assumed for all random generators? Or can the sequence of states also have a lasso shape, i.e. 1->2->3->4->5->6->4->5->6->4->... In the latter, one should first find a state within the cycle, which can be done by incrementing one generator once and the other generator twice until they are found to be equal and then apply the above described method to find the period. Algorithmic question: is there a faster way?

Comment: @MaartenHilferink: I'm not aware of any that have a lasso-like shape, but I guess that doesn't mean one couldn't exist. I don't know of a whole lot better way to detect a lasso-like cycle than the rabbit/turtle method you already noted. For many generators, *any* method of cycle-finding is known to be impractical.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Von Neumann's [middle-square method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method) has a lasso-shape for some starting points.  Maarten's comment gives a good description of [Floyd's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare), a.k.a. tortoise-and-hare.  There's a similar algorithm by Brent which has the same complexity is claimed to run faster on average.

Comment: @MaartenHilferink So if I understand correctly. We first need to use the tortoise-and-hare algorithm by incrementing one generator once and the other twice until both states are equal and then apply Jerry's algorithm?

Comment: Here is a proof of Floyd's cycle chasing algorithm: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913499/proof-of-floyd-cycle-chasing-tortoise-and-hare

Comment: @BigLudinski: Yes, first tortoise-and-hare run until hare catches in with tortoise, then hare can have a rest (which he really needs if they were running a good random generator) while tortoise walks Jerry's loop,